# Linear regression on a truncated dataframe not working

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that i have grouped and then extracted the slope between values of 2 columns. The code is as below. `grouped_full= data_train.groupby(['Cycle', 'Type'])
slope_full = (grouped_full.apply(lambda x: linregress(x['Time'], x['Values']).slope)).reset_index(name='Slope')`

I get the slope in a new column called "Slope".
Now, I am trying to do the same thing for just the first 1700 rows in each grouped item. To get the 1700 rows, I have used the code as follows `grouped_small = data_train.groupby(['Cycle', 'Type']).head(1700)`
I have printed & checked, the dataframe is good.
However, when i try to extract the slope on this using `slope_small = (grouped_small.apply(lambda a: linregress(a['Time'], a['Values']).slope)).reset_index(name='Slope2')` i encounter the error

```
KeyError: ('Time', 'occurred at index Cycle')
```

It is exactly the same code. I am not sure why i am encountering this error. What should i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"grouped_full" is a `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy` hence apply comman will work on that.grouped_small is a complete dataframe `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` & apply will not work. So i did the following & it is working `grouped_small = data_train.groupby(['Cycle', 'Type']).head(1700)
grouped_small2 = grouped_small.groupby(['Cycle', 'Type'])
slope_small = (grouped_small2.apply(lambda x: linregress(x['Time'], x['Values']).slope)).reset_index(name='Slope_small')`